# Rails: Make application internal logs accessible via admin interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Within my Rails app I want to do some simple logging on actions performed by app users (separate from the Rails log used by me as a developper), that is accessible to the app's admin via log download or displayed within the app's admin page.

Can I use somehow the built in logger to keep such a log in a separate file and access this file from within the app?

Comment: Do you want the ability to somehow mark the parts of your app that should be logged for the users. Or do you want the production log itself to be accessible for users - or only certain parts of the production log?

Comment: No, I want to log actions in the Application logic in a separate file. The user should be able to recreate the current status of a product through the (product-) log.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [`log_me`](https://github.com/icatcher-at/log_me). It's not a gem (yet), but you could simply clone it or copy/paste it, since it's not that big...

Comment: Looks promising. Trying it out.

Comment: Where do I put init.rb? or it's code? It does not seem to get called by default. log_me in a controller class raises undefined method. Never used non-gemmed plugins before...

Comment: Try to put it in an initializer under `config/initializers`

Comment: ok in there it executes the init.rb but now it does not find log_me. I tried putting log_me.rb into lib and also into vendor/log_me/lib . Did not work. Where do I have to put which file from https://github.com/icatcher-at/log_me ???